# How to log RestAssured Request and Response information log in ExtentReports logs

Tags: java, rest-assured, extentreports

I am using rest-assured lib and extent report for reporting,

```
ValidatableResponse reponseManualLead = given().header("Accept", "application/json")
                .contentType("application/json").header("Authorization", access_token)
                .body(requestBody).log().body().when()
                .put(losdevUrl + "/endUrl").then().log().all();
```

log().all() : Pritn log of request/reponse in console log , I need that to be log in extentreport , can we do that.

```
ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.INFO, "Response is:<br>" + "here");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189800/4762087

Comment: U can use this [artifact](https://github.com/grasshopper7/rest-assured-extent-report-plugin) and [article](https://ghchirp.tech/3791/) for creating a Spark Report, just by adding a filter to rest calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended usage to include JSON request/response is via `MarkupHelper` as in the documentation: http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/#markup-helpers-codeblock

```
Markup m = MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(json, CodeLanguage.JSON);
test.pass(m);

// shorthand
test.pass(MarkupHelper.createCodeBlock(json, CodeLanguage.JSON));
```

The code block will be prettified and display like so:

[image]